# Can you get the fileId from the filename/path with the Google.Apis.Drive.v3 DriveService

Tags: .net, google-drive-api

I'm writing a service that I would like to be able to delete files from Google Drive. But I would like the file identifier to be the filename and path. It looks like the Google.Apis.Drive.v3 API only accepts the fileId, which I don't know how to get without using the UI. Is there a way to get the fileId for a file in Drive with only the file name and path?

Or is there another way to find the fileId without using the UI?

Here's the API docs: https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Drive.v3/latest/api/Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.html

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do a query with the name of the file, mime type, and other options to search the files. For example:

```
var request = service.Files.List();
request.PageSize = 1000;
request.Q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name = 'test_folder'"
var results = await request.ExecuteAsync();

foreach (var driveFile in results.Files)
      {
       Console.WriteLine($"{driveFile.Name}  {driveFile.MimeType}  {driveFile.Id}");
       }
```

Which will search folders with the name `"test_folder"`. You can see other queries available in the Google documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files#examples), and the queries operators available [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms#operators). Lastly, you can review the Google Drive supported MIME types [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/mime-types), so you can change the query to other files, not just folders.

With this sample, you get the fields `File.Id`, `MimeType` and `Name`. You can also get the fields:

- `kind`
- `id`
- `name`
- `mimeType`
- etc. The full list can be seen in the [overview](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)

I found the following [blog](https://www.daimto.com/how-to-search-for-files-with-the-google-drive-api-and-net-core/) with more information about searching files on Google Drive; it has some other samples that you can use.

**Reference:**

- [Query string examples](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files#examples)
- [Search query terms and operators](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms#operators)
- [Google Drive supported MIME types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/mime-types)
- [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)